# 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'unlink' error

Tags: scene, data-blocks

I'm trying to remove object and free from memory. I googled some, and found an old article

https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-clean-memory-after-running-a-script/608062

I copied the script and executed on my blender 2.82. But the console returned error at the line 78.

```
scene = bpy.data.scenes[0]
# Unlink and remove object first
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    scene.objects.unlink(ob) # At this line
```

It says, 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'unlink'.
I think it's because the API changed during update, but I can't figure out how to change it. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
scene = bpy.data.scenes[0]
    
# Unlink and remove object first
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.unlink(ob)
```

Also maybe remove all objects too?

```
scene = bpy.data.scenes[0]

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(ob)
    
# Unlink and remove object first
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    print(ob)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.unlink(ob)
```

Comment: Just a little note. It is not necessary to unlink objects following objects.remove(). This is done by default: remove(object, do_unlink=True, do_id_user=True, do_ui_user=True)

Comment: ah thanks! good info relaxed